# Fatal Signal 11 on android music streaming app

Tags: android, c, memory, crash, android-ndk

I am using this project to code a music streaming-application on android devices: https://github.com/spotify/psyonspotify

Unfortunately, my app crashes randomly. I have tried to debug the c-code with ndk-stack. According to the output the problem lies in the following line:

```
assert(SL_RESULT_SUCCESS != result);
```

(l.92 in sounddriver.cpp). I have tried to change and/or comment this line out, but the error still remains...

It seems to be some kind of problem related to incorrect memory allocation but it doesn't seem to have anything to do with the buffer size, as there seems to be enough storage size left (see logging output)

```
09-03 20:00:50.556: I/DEBUG(4356): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
09-03 20:00:50.556: I/DEBUG(4356): Build fingerprint: 'samsung/p4notewifixx/p4notewifiww:4.1.2/JZO54K/N8010XXUCMH2:user/release-keys'
09-03 20:00:50.556: I/DEBUG(4356): pid: 2103, tid: 2204, name: Network Thread  >>> com.masterarbeit.wheel4tunes <<<
09-03 20:00:50.556: I/DEBUG(4356): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr deadbaad
09-03 20:00:50.576: D/dalvikvm(2150): GC_EXPLICIT freed 122K, 43% free 29046K/50183K, paused 3ms+8ms, total 123ms
09-03 20:00:50.636: I/DEBUG(4356):     r0 00000027  r1 deadbaad  r2 40115b0c  r3 00000000
09-03 20:00:50.636: I/DEBUG(4356):     r4 00000000  r5 5e791acc  r6 00000800  r7 00000002
09-03 20:00:50.636: I/DEBUG(4356):     r8 00000000  r9 00000001  sl 00004e1f  fp 5e791b1c
09-03 20:00:50.636: I/DEBUG(4356):     ip 00004000  sp 5e791ac8  lr 400e7c65  pc 400e42fe  cpsr 60000030
09-03 20:00:50.636: I/DEBUG(4356):     d0  3f7aaaab0142ff80  d1  3ff0000042c80000
09-03 20:00:50.636: I/DEBUG(4356):     d2  000000003f800000  d3  443c000000000000
09-03 20:00:50.636: I/DEBUG(4356):     d4  0000000000000000  d5  3f80000000000000
09-03 20:00:50.636: I/DEBUG(4356):     d6  3f80000000000000  d7  0142ff803f800000
09-03 20:00:50.636: I/DEBUG(4356):     d8  0000000000000000  d9  0000000000000000
09-03 20:00:50.636: I/DEBUG(4356):     d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
09-03 20:00:50.636: I/DEBUG(4356):     d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
09-03 20:00:50.636: I/DEBUG(4356):     d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
09-03 20:00:50.636: I/DEBUG(4356):     d16 41742ff808000000  d17 3fe0000000000000
09-03 20:00:50.636: I/DEBUG(4356):     d18 0000000000000000  d19 2000000840070c00
09-03 20:00:50.636: I/DEBUG(4356):     d20 0000000000000000  d21 0000000000000000
09-03 20:00:50.636: I/DEBUG(4356):     d22 0000000000000000  d23 0000000000000000
09-03 20:00:50.636: I/DEBUG(4356):     d24 0000000000000000  d25 0000000000000000
09-03 20:00:50.636: I/DEBUG(4356):     d26 0000000000000000  d27 0000000000000000
09-03 20:00:50.636: I/DEBUG(4356):     d28 0000000000000000  d29 0000000000000000
09-03 20:00:50.636: I/DEBUG(4356):     d30 0000000000000000  d31 0000000000000000
09-03 20:00:50.636: I/DEBUG(4356):     scr 20000010
09-03 20:00:50.641: I/DEBUG(4356): backtrace:
09-03 20:00:50.641: I/DEBUG(4356):     #00  pc 000182fe  /system/lib/libc.so
09-03 20:00:50.641: I/DEBUG(4356):     #01  pc 0000dc04  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+4)
09-03 20:00:50.641: I/DEBUG(4356):     #02  pc 0001f0bf  /system/lib/libc.so (__assert2+30)
09-03 20:00:50.641: I/DEBUG(4356):     #03  pc 000121f0  /data/data/com.masterarbeit.wheel4tunes/lib/libspotifywrapper.so (enqueue(short*, int)+176)
09-03 20:00:50.641: I/DEBUG(4356):     #04  pc 00012568  /data/data/com.masterarbeit.wheel4tunes/lib/libspotifywrapper.so (music_delivery(sp_session*, sp_audioformat const*, void const*, int)+620)
09-03 20:00:50.641: I/DEBUG(4356):     #05  pc 00168758  /data/data/com.masterarbeit.wheel4tunes/lib/libspotify.so
09-03 20:00:50.641: I/DEBUG(4356): stack:
09-03 20:00:50.641: I/DEBUG(4356):          5e791a88  5aa21e70  
09-03 20:00:50.641: I/DEBUG(4356):          5e791a8c  5a1b1d2c  /system/framework/twframework-res.apk
09-03 20:00:50.641: I/DEBUG(4356):          5e791a90  40004fb0  
09-03 20:00:50.641: I/DEBUG(4356):          5e791a94  00000000  
09-03 20:00:50.641: I/DEBUG(4356):          5e791a98  00000000  
09-03 20:00:50.641: I/DEBUG(4356):          5e791a9c  00000000  
09-03 20:00:50.641: I/DEBUG(4356):          5e791aa0  40110774  /system/lib/libc.so
09-03 20:00:50.641: I/DEBUG(4356):          5e791aa4  40115d10  
09-03 20:00:50.641: I/DEBUG(4356):          5e791aa8  00000000  
09-03 20:00:50.641: I/DEBUG(4356):          5e791aac  400e7c65  /system/lib/libc.so (_fwalk+32)
09-03 20:00:50.641: I/DEBUG(4356):          5e791ab0  00000001  
09-03 20:00:50.641: I/DEBUG(4356):          5e791ab4  5e791acc  
09-03 20:00:50.641: I/DEBUG(4356):          5e791ab8  00000800  
09-03 20:00:50.641: I/DEBUG(4356):          5e791abc  00000002  
09-03 20:00:50.641: I/DEBUG(4356):          5e791ac0  df0027ad  
09-03 20:00:50.641: I/DEBUG(4356):          5e791ac4  00000000  
09-03 20:00:50.641: I/DEBUG(4356):     #00  5e791ac8  5e3e1e48  /data/data/com.masterarbeit.wheel4tunes/lib/libspotifywrapper.so
09-03 20:00:50.641: I/DEBUG(4356):          5e791acc  fffffbdf  
09-03 20:00:50.641: I/DEBUG(4356):          5e791ad0  40106ecc  /system/lib/libc.so
09-03 20:00:50.641: I/DEBUG(4356):          5e791ad4  00000800  
09-03 20:00:50.641: I/DEBUG(4356):          5e791ad8  00000002  
09-03 20:00:50.641: I/DEBUG(4356):          5e791adc  400e71d1  /system/lib/libc.so (fprintf+16)
09-03 20:00:50.641: I/DEBUG(4356):          5e791ae0  40110718  /system/lib/libc.so
09-03 20:00:50.641: I/DEBUG(4356):          5e791ae4  5e3e1e48  /data/data/com.masterarbeit.wheel4tunes/lib/libspotifywrapper.so
09-03 20:00:50.641: I/DEBUG(4356):          5e791ae8  40106ecc  /system/lib/libc.so
09-03 20:00:50.641: I/DEBUG(4356):          5e791aec  400d9c08  /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_clone)
09-03 20:00:50.641: I/DEBUG(4356):     #01  5e791af0  5e791af0  
09-03 20:00:50.641: I/DEBUG(4356):          5e791af4  400eb0c3  /system/lib/libc.so (__assert2+34)
09-03 20:00:50.641: I/DEBUG(4356):     #02  5e791af8  0000005c  
09-03 20:00:50.641: I/DEBUG(4356):          5e791afc  5e3e2178  /data/data/com.masterarbeit.wheel4tunes/lib/libspotifywrapper.so
09-03 20:00:50.641: I/DEBUG(4356):          5e791b00  5e3e2178  /data/data/com.masterarbeit.wheel4tunes/lib/libspotifywrapper.so
09-03 20:00:50.646: I/DEBUG(4356):          5e791b04  5e3d91f4  /data/data/com.masterarbeit.wheel4tunes/lib/libspotifywrapper.so (enqueue(short*, int)+180)
09-03 20:00:50.646: I/DEBUG(4356): memory near r2:
09-03 20:00:50.646: I/DEBUG(4356):     40115aec 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
09-03 20:00:50.646: I/DEBUG(4356):     40115afc 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
09-03 20:00:50.646: I/DEBUG(4356):     40115b0c 00000001 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
09-03 20:00:50.646: I/DEBUG(4356):     40115b1c 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
09-03 20:00:50.646: I/DEBUG(4356):     40115b2c 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
09-03 20:00:50.646: I/DEBUG(4356): memory near r5:
09-03 20:00:50.646: I/DEBUG(4356):     5e791aac 400e7c65 00000001 5e791acc 00000800  e|.@......y^....
09-03 20:00:50.646: I/DEBUG(4356):     5e791abc 00000002 df0027ad 00000000 5e3e1e48  .....'......H.>^
09-03 20:00:50.646: I/DEBUG(4356):     5e791acc fffffbdf 40106ecc 00000800 00000002  .....n.@........
09-03 20:00:50.646: I/DEBUG(4356):     5e791adc 400e71d1 40110718 5e3e1e48 40106ecc  .q.@...@H.>^.n.@
09-03 20:00:50.646: I/DEBUG(4356):     5e791aec 400d9c08 5e791af0 400eb0c3 0000005c  ...@..y^...@\...
09-03 20:00:50.646: I/DEBUG(4356): memory near sl:
09-03 20:00:50.646: I/DEBUG(4356):     00004dfc ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
09-03 20:00:50.646: I/DEBUG(4356):     00004e0c ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
09-03 20:00:50.646: I/DEBUG(4356):     00004e1c ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
09-03 20:00:50.646: I/DEBUG(4356):     00004e2c ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
09-03 20:00:50.646: I/DEBUG(4356):     00004e3c ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
09-03 20:00:50.646: I/DEBUG(4356): memory near fp:
09-03 20:00:50.646: I/DEBUG(4356):     5e791afc 5e3e2178 5e3e2178 5e3d91f4 0000c000  x!>^x!>^..=^....
09-03 20:00:50.646: I/DEBUG(4356):     5e791b0c 5e3e50c0 5e3e1f18 00000000 5e791b3c  .P>^..>^....<.y^
09-03 20:00:50.646: I/DEBUG(4356):     5e791b1c 5e3d956c 00000800 5f44b10c 5e791b44  l.=^......D_D.y^
09-03 20:00:50.646: I/DEBUG(4356):     5e791b2c 40004698 00002000 0000c000 00000004  .F.@. ..........
09-03 20:00:50.646: I/DEBUG(4356):     5e791b3c 5e32975c 00000000 00000000 0000ac44  \.2^........D...
09-03 20:00:50.646: I/DEBUG(4356): memory near ip:
09-03 20:00:50.646: I/DEBUG(4356):     00003fe0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
09-03 20:00:50.646: I/DEBUG(4356):     00003ff0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
09-03 20:00:50.651: I/DEBUG(4356):     00004000 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
09-03 20:00:50.651: I/DEBUG(4356):     00004010 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
09-03 20:00:50.651: I/DEBUG(4356):     00004020 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
09-03 20:00:50.651: I/DEBUG(4356): memory near sp:
09-03 20:00:50.651: I/DEBUG(4356):     5e791aa8 00000000 400e7c65 00000001 5e791acc  ....e|.@......y^
09-03 20:00:50.651: I/DEBUG(4356):     5e791ab8 00000800 00000002 df0027ad 00000000  .........'......
09-03 20:00:50.651: I/DEBUG(4356):     5e791ac8 5e3e1e48 fffffbdf 40106ecc 00000800  H.>^.....n.@....
09-03 20:00:50.651: I/DEBUG(4356):     5e791ad8 00000002 400e71d1 40110718 5e3e1e48  .....q.@...@H.>^
09-03 20:00:50.651: I/DEBUG(4356):     5e791ae8 40106ecc 400d9c08 5e791af0 400eb0c3  .n.@...@..y^...@
09-03 20:00:50.651: I/DEBUG(4356): code around pc:
09-03 20:00:50.651: I/DEBUG(4356):     400e42dc e000b164 6823461c d1fb2b00 68e3e026  d....F#h.+..&..h
09-03 20:00:50.651: I/DEBUG(4356):     400e42ec 4a17b123 447a2401 47986014 20274911  #..J.$zD.`.G.I' 
09-03 20:00:50.651: I/DEBUG(4356):     400e42fc 70082400 ebb2f7f4 f7f52106 a902ecf2  .$.p.....!......
09-03 20:00:50.651: I/DEBUG(4356):     400e430c f04f2006 460a5380 94029304 f7f59403  . O..S.F........
09-03 20:00:50.651: I/DEBUG(4356):     400e431c 4629e8d0 20024622 e8d8f7f5 eb9ef7f4  ..)F"F. ........
09-03 20:00:50.651: I/DEBUG(4356): code around lr:
09-03 20:00:50.651: I/DEBUG(4356):     400e7c44 41f0e92d 4c0b2600 447c4680 68a56824  -..A.&.L.F|D$h.h
09-03 20:00:50.651: I/DEBUG(4356):     400e7c54 e0076867 300cf9b5 dd022b00 47c04628  gh.....0.+..(F.G
09-03 20:00:50.651: I/DEBUG(4356):     400e7c64 35544306 d5f53f01 2c006824 4630d1ef  .CT5.?..$h.,..0F
09-03 20:00:50.651: I/DEBUG(4356):     400e7c74 81f0e8bd 000288b2 43f0e92d fb01461f  ........-..C.F..
09-03 20:00:50.651: I/DEBUG(4356):     400e7c84 f8dff602 b0878058 44f8460c 8000f8d8  ....X....F.D....
09-03 20:00:50.651: I/DEBUG(4356): memory map around fault addr deadbaad:
09-03 20:00:50.651: I/DEBUG(4356):     beb7b000-beb9c000 [stack]
09-03 20:00:50.651: I/DEBUG(4356):     (no map for address)
09-03 20:00:50.651: I/DEBUG(4356):     ffff0000-ffff1000 [vectors]
```

Unfortunately I am not very experienced in handling or debugging c-code. It would be great if someone could point me into the right direction! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If `assert(SL_RESULT_SUCCESS != result);` is firing than your problem is related to `SLresult result = (*bqPlayerBufferQueue)->Enqueue(bqPlayerBufferQueue, buffer, size);`

`SLAndroidSimpleBufferQueueItf` is implemented in OpenSL. Are you properly initializing the audio player with init_audio_player() before trying to enqueue to the buffer?

Some ideas for debugging: Explore `SLAndroidSimpleBufferQueueItf` to understand its interface and verify all assumptions are met before calling Enqueue. Also look for other return codes it provides. If its providing a helpful error code that will make your life easier.

Also look at how you call into psyonspotify.so to ensure that you are properly adhering to its interface and assumptions (i.e any init functions that are required).